# mix link docker containers with network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have the following setup:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
eab42051ca26        web-www:20180804             "node run.js"            8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        3000/tcp             web-www
63ec48e93a77        jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   9 hours ago         Up 9 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   nginx-proxy-server
463ffd55260b        fiorix/freegeoip             "/go/bin/freegeoip"      9 hours ago         Up 9 hours          8080/tcp             freegeoip
bdc702c370ec        euvat                        "/usr/local/bin/euva…"   9 hours ago         Up 9 hours          3000/tcp             euvat
40c07de732fa        redis:4.0.10                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 hours ago         Up 9 hours          6379/tcp             redis-www
76831834f59d        mongo:4.0                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 hours ago         Up 9 hours          27017/tcp            mongo-www
```

where my web-www node.js app connects to redis and mongo via the

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
74d8f38aca38        bridge              bridge              local
1c894a7fa176        host                host                local
ca02c5ccac55        network-www         bridge              local
7226d9cc5360        none                null                local
```

my run.sh file is like:

```
OLDAPP="$(docker ps --all --quiet --filter=name="$APP")"
if [ -n "$OLDAPP" ]; then
  docker stop $OLDAPP && docker rm $OLDAPP
fi
docker run --name web-www \
    --network network-www \
   --link euvat:euvat \
   --link freegeoip:freegeoip \
   --env VIRTUAL_HOST=araweelo.local \
   --env-file /env/web-www.env \
   web-www:20180804.182446
```

so, now i am starting a new development stack `dev-www` for example, so i will create the `network-dev`, launch `redis-dev` and `mongo-dev` but want to share  the `euvat` and `freegeoip` containers with the `web-www` container.

is this the correct way to do this or is there an alternative method?

any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker [links are deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and maybe removed soon.

It's better to create the networks, containers ahead of time and join the container to the network

```
docker network create network-www

docker run --name web-www \
   --env VIRTUAL_HOST=araweelo.local \
   --env-file /env/web-www.env \
   web-www:20180804.182446

docker network connect network-www web-www
docker network connect network-www euvat
docker network connect network-www freegeoip
```

This above commands will create a `network-www` user-defined bridge network and connect `euvat`, `web-www` and `freegeoip` containers to that network.

Replace/add containers as required. Might be a better idea to write a compose file which brings up the containers in a single command

Comment: cool, i didn't realize that you can connect to multiple networks